# dependency graph is unresolvable; found these conflicting requirements:

Tags: swift, freetype, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to import this dependency:
https://github.com/PureSwift/CFreeType

but I am getting this error:

```
Fetching https://github.com/PureSwift/CFreeType.git
error: dependency graph is unresolvable; found these conflicting requirements:

Dependencies: 
    https://github.com/PureSwift/CFreeType.git @ 1.0.4
```

The repo has a 1.0.4 tag. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is my Package.swift:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftPlot",
    products: [
       // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
       .library(
       name: "SwiftPlot",
       targets: ["AGG", "lodepng", "CPPAGGRenderer", "CAGGRenderer", "SwiftPlot", "SVGRenderer", "AGGRenderer"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url:"https://github.com/PureSwift/CFreeType.git", .exact("1.0.4")),
    ],
    targets: [
        //relevant targets
    ],
    cxxLanguageStandard: .cxx11
)
```